# Plot a Cumulative Distribution Function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, cdf

I'm getting a strange looking graph from my cdf function. If I use ecdf, I get the graph I expect. But I get a tangled mess that looks like it contains the right data, but in some wrong order.

```
SNR = exprnd(1,1000,1); 
Cap = 1*log2(1+SNR); % unit bandwidth

[f,x] = ecdf(Cap);
figure(2);
plot( x,f);

cdf_Cap = cdf('Exponential', Cap, 1);
figure(3);
plot( Cap, cdf_Cap);

figure(4);
cdfplot(Cap);
```

Figure 2 shows the expected result: [image]

and Figure 3 shows:
[image]

I'm sure its the right data, and just requires some kind of absolute function, or sorting function. I just have no idea what that would be. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need to necessarily sort it. You can plot the function without connecting lines like `plot( Cap, cdf_Cap,'o')`, although for the cdf you probably do want to sort it and connect the lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `Cap` is not monotonically increasing. I think you might sort it before plotting.

On `figure(3)`, replace this:

```
plot( Cap, cdf_Cap);
```

With this:

```
[~, idx] = sort(Cap);
plot( Cap(idx), cdf_Cap(idx));
```

Now the data will be plotted in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was expecting. Cheers =)